# AWS S3 object in folder key mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

According to [Object Key and Metadata - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html), Amazon S3 buckets have a flat structure, meaning that an object created in a folder `folder1/object1.txt` would have the key `folder1/object1.txt`. However there is a discrepancy between the docs and what the AWS console shows.

When you click on the checkbox next to the `object1.txt` the properties panel slides in from the right and there is a key property under the overview section that reads key `object1.txt`. This according to the documentation is incorrect. Additionally if you click on the object link the new overview screen shows a different panel in which they key is `folder1/object1.txt`.

**My Question is**: What is the reason for this discrepancy and which panel is displaying the correct information? Is the key represented in the first panel something entirely different than the s3 object key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is correct.

However, since humans enjoy the concept of folders and directories, Amazon S3 provides something called a **Common Prefix**, which is similar to the concept of a **path**.

When listing the contents of a bucket, paths (effectively keys without the final "object name") are provided are a list of `CommonPrefixes`. The AWS Management Console uses this to allow users to step through folder hierarchies.

However, the Key of all objects include their full path.

Here's something interesting... if a user clicks "New Folder" in the Amazon S3 management console, then a zero-length file is created with the name of the folder. This causes the folder to appear as a common prefix, even if no files exist "inside" the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Correct object key would obviously be `folder1/object1.txt`.

As for the reason for the discrepancy I'd sign it off to a poor UI decision.